# How do I retrieve a value from a object in an method to use it in another method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view

I know that this question as been ask plenty of time but it does not seem to be working for me. Could you please help or provide me with a link with a similar question?

I have an object “ws” and I would like to capture the **WorkShiftID** so I can use it in CreateSharedView.

Ps: Sorry for my english, I am new to c# so please bear with me. Thank you

EDIT:I would like to retrieve ws.WorkShiftId from Create to put it in task.WorkShiftId in CreateSharedView. Is it possible?

````
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewData["HoleId"] = new SelectList(_context.Hole, "HoleId", "HoleName");
            ViewData["SupplierId"] = new SelectList(_context.Supplier, "SupplierId", "SupplierName");
            ViewData["SurveyLocationId"] = new SelectList(_context.SurveyLocation, "SurveyLocationId", "SurveyLocation1");
            ViewData["ZoneId"] = new SelectList(_context.Zone, "ZoneId", "ZoneName");

            return View();
        }

        // POST: WorkShiftDetailViewModels/Create
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create(WorkShiftDetailViewModel workShiftDetailViewModel)
        {

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                WorkShift ws = new WorkShift();
                ws.StartDay = workShiftDetailViewModel.StartDay;
                ws.EndDay = workShiftDetailViewModel.EndDay;
                ws.SupplierId = workShiftDetailViewModel.SupplierId;
                ws.SurveyLocationId = 1;
                ws.ZoneId = workShiftDetailViewModel.ZoneId;
                ws.HoleId = workShiftDetailViewModel.HoleId;
                _context.Add(ws);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

                foreach (WorkerViewModel member in workShiftDetailViewModel.WorkShiftEmployees)
                {
                    if (member.isDeleted == false) {
                        WorkShiftTeam emp = new WorkShiftTeam();
                        emp.EmployeeId = member.EmployeeId;
                        emp.RoleId = member.RoleId;
                        emp.WorkShiftId = ws.WorkShiftId;
                        test = ws.WorkShiftId;
                        _context.Add(emp);
                    }
                }

                return RedirectToAction(nameof(CreateSharedView));

            }

        public IActionResult CreateSharedView()
        {

            ViewData["TaskId"] = new SelectList(_context.Task, "TaskId", "TaskDescription");
            ViewData["WorkShiftTaskId"] = new SelectList(_context.WorkShift, "WorkShiftId", "WorkShiftId");

            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CreateSharedView(SharedViewModel sharedViewModel, 
                                                          SurveyViewModel surveyViewModel,
                                                          WorkShiftTask task)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                WorkShiftTask task = new WorkShiftTask();
                task.WorkShiftTaskId = sharedViewModel.WorkShiftTaskId;
                task.TaskId = sharedViewModel.TaskId;
                _context.Add(task);

                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            return View(sharedViewModel);
        }```
````

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. When you say "use it in another method", which method are you referring to?

Comment: Sorry, I would like to retrieve ws.WorkShiftId from Create to put it in task.WorkShiftId in CreateSharedView. is it possible?

Comment: Do you want to call the GET or the POST version of CreateSharedView() from within Create? It looks like you are already calling RedirectToAction() while naming CreateSharedView but that will resolve to the GET method. So I assume you want to call the POST method?

Comment: @robbpriestley yes, exactly. sorry my question wasn't clear thank you for taking the time to understand what i am trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simpliest way is to use `Session` to store and get the `ws.WorkShiftId`,after [configuring session state](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-3.0#configure-session-state) in your startup,

In `Create` POST action:

```
HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("wsId", ws.WorkShiftId);
```

In `CreateSharedView` POST action:

```
task.WorkShiftId = HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("wsId");
```

Another more complicated way is that you could pass the `ws.WorkShiftId` as parameter when you redirect or use `TempData`:

`Create` POST Action:

```
 //Or TempData["myId"] = ws.WorkShiftId;
 return RedirectToAction(nameof(CreateSharedView),new { workShiftId= ws.WorkShiftId});
```

`CreateSharedView` GET Action:

```
public IActionResult CreateSharedView([FromQuery]int? workShiftId)
{
    //Or  ViewData["workShiftId"] = TempData["myId"]
    ViewData["workShiftId"] = workShiftId;
    return View();
}
```

`CreateSharedView` View:

```
<form asp-action="CreateSharedView">

    <input type="hidden" name="workShiftId" value="@ViewBag.workShiftId" />
</form>
```

`CreateSharedView` POST Action

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateSharedView(    int workShiftId, 
                                                      SharedViewModel sharedViewModel, 
                                                      SurveyViewModel surveyViewModel,
                                                      WorkShiftTask task)
{
      task.WorkShiftTaskId = workShiftId;
}
```

Comment: Your solution is perfect! You got exactly what I was trying to do. I have been stuck on this for a while and I cannot believe both your solution works! Thank you very much for taking your time to answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

The CreateSharedView POST method basically just adds a WorkShiftTask to the database. So rather than mess around trying to call one POST method from another, just do this from inside the Create() method:

```
foreach (WorkerViewModel member in workShiftDetailViewModel.WorkShiftEmployees)
{
    if (member.isDeleted == false)
    {
        WorkShiftTeam emp = new WorkShiftTeam();
        emp.EmployeeId = member.EmployeeId;
        emp.RoleId = member.RoleId;
        emp.WorkShiftId = ws.WorkShiftId;
        // test = ws.WorkShiftId; test? no. defined where?
        _context.Add(emp);

        WorkShiftTask task = new WorkShiftTask();
        task.WorkShiftId = ws.WorkShiftId;  // There's the ws.WorkShiftId you were mentioning...
        // set other members of "task"
        _context.Add(task);

        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying!! Sadly this does not work. the moment, i go to CreateSharedView i lose the wsID.

Comment: That's what I was trying to say: don't even bother going to CreateSharedView, just do everything from the single POST controller (Create).